# javascript node.js converting Numbers to uint8 for serialization into typed arrays binary

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, buffer

How do I convert Javascript's Number into lesser precision suitable for writing to a binary stream (bytearray, node.js's Buffer, typed array, dataview etc)?

My goal is to serialize a large collection of small numbers into a binary string for efficient sending/storage, in a fashion that works in javascript on both server side (node.js) and client/browser side.

My problem is at the moment, Javascript internally only stores its `Number`s as 32bit Ints or 64bit doubles, and I'm lost on how to convert or write those to a buffer.  Currenlty they are all being written as doubles, so that the space required to send is several times what it could be, and there are lots of libraries to help read/write buffers, but if I write a javascript `Number` to a say `writeUInt8` it gives me an error that the value is outside the bounds.

So ideally say I have values like so, with the ideal size and current size.

```
    VALUE -> BITS
 -------------------------------
       1  ->  1 bit  vs  64 bit
     255  ->  8 bit  vs  64 bit
 1203423  -> 16 bit  vs  64 bit
 -------------------------------
   TOTAL     25 bit  vs 192 bit (13% of the size)
```

Node has things like:

```
buffer.writeUInt8(value, offset, noAssert=false)
buffer.writeUInt16BE(value, offset, noAssert=false)
```

so I know it's possible to write, I just don't know how. I don't see any options on `parseInt`, `parseFloat`.

Comment: The functions that allow you to write know that they'll be getting JavaScript Number instances, and they do the appropriate thing to truncate the values. Of course, you have to make sure the values you present are in range (via bitwise operators or whatever). You simply can't fit a number like 5000 in an 8-bit value.

Comment: Maybe this can help: Typed Array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Comment: What range of numbers are you looking at storing?

Comment: BTW - Though the exact internal details may vary, JavaScript exposes *all* numbers as a 64bit floating point number.  53bit integers (and, by extension, 32bit integers as well) map nicely on this space with no loss of precision.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks.

Turns out that not all libraries support that.  I was using Bops
https://www.npmjs.org/package/bops

Switching over to jDataView https://github.com/jDataView/jDataView resolved the error.